# DataContractSerializer compatibility after namespace changed

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class need to be serialized.

```
namespace serializedobject
{
[DataContract]
public class Class1
{
    string string1_;
    string string2_;
    EntityA entity_;

    [DataMember]
    public string string3
    {
        get { return string1_; }
        set { string1_ = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string string2
    {
        get { return string2_; }
        set { string2_ = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public EntityA Entity
    {
        get { return entity_; }
        set { entity_ = value; }
    }

    public static Class1 FromXML(string desc)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
            writer.Write(desc);
            writer.Flush();

            ms.Seek(0, 0);
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Class1));
            return (Class1)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }

    public string ToXML()
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Class1));
            ser.WriteObject(ms, this);
            ms.Seek(0, 0);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class EntityA
{
    string name_;
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name_; }
        set { name_ = value; }
    }
}
}
```

it is works fine with FromXML and ToXML. one of serialized context like:

```
<Class1 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/serializedobject"    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Entity><Name>az</Name></Entity><string2 i:nil="true"/><string3>test</string3></Class1>
```

Later I need to move class EntityA to another namespace "outside", now the serialized context like:

```
<Class1 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/serializedobject" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Entity xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/outside"><a:Name>az</a:Name></Entity><string2 i:nil="true"/><string3>test</string3></Class1>
```

but now the serialized xml which created before change namespace can't be deserialized correctly. I guess this is because of for class "EntityA" changed namespace (xmlns:a added).
does anybody run into the problem before? any suggestion?

Comment: Try [`[DataContract(Namespace="")]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in both versions of the class.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that would also be a breaking change; I think you mean `Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/serializedobject"`

Comment: @MarcGravell No, I really mean "" - I'm just going to add a code sample. I'm assuming here that he hasn't changed the namespace yet - i.e. he can make this change BEFORE persisting any data. If not, then we must apply it to the new class. I'll add that to my reply too.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I interpreted the question as "we've already started persisting data", which is why I'm leaning towards preserving the existing behaviour / layout - but I agree that the `Namespace=""` is a **preferable** layout, and in many ways it bothers me that the default is so horrible. Contrast with `XmlSerializer` which defaults to the empty namespace.

Comment: @MarcGravell You're probably right - to be on the safe side, I addressed both scenarios. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop the namespace being added to the XML by specifying [`[DataContract(Namespace="")]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This relies on you setting that attribute BEFORE you save any xml code.

You can use this approach only if you have not already serialized any data, so this is the approach you would use when first designing a class to be serialized.

(If you have already got serialized data that you must deal with, see the second part of my answer below.)

This code sample has the two classes called `Demo` in two different namespaces, `Test1` and `Test2`.

We serialize the code using the class from one namespace, and deserialize it using the class from the other namespace:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    namespace Test1
    {
        [DataContract(Namespace="")]

        public sealed class Demo
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
    }

    namespace Test2
    {
        [DataContract(Namespace="")]

        public sealed class Demo
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
    }

    sealed class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            string filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
            var demo1 = new Test1.Demo {Value = "DEMO"};
            ToFile(filename, demo1);

            var demo2 = FromFile<Test2.Demo>(filename);
            Console.WriteLine(demo2.Value);
        }

        public static void ToFile(string filename, object obj)
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());

            using (var streamWriter = File.CreateText(filename))
            using (var xmlWriter    = XmlWriter.Create(streamWriter, new XmlWriterSettings{Indent = true}))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
        }

        public static T FromFile<T>(string filename)
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (var textReader = File.OpenText(filename))
            using (var xmlReader  = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
            {
                return (T)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
            }
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you have already serialized data without the `Namespace=""` attribute, then you will need instead to apply the appropriate namespace to the new class:

```
namespace Test1
{
    [DataContract]

    public sealed class Demo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Test2
{
    // Note the namespace includes both nested namespaces, i.e. ConsoleApp1.Test1

    [DataContract(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApp1.Test1")]

    public sealed class Demo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```