# Changing namespace for DataContracts in a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

After a major refactoring of our client/service system written in C# with WCF services, we have moved all the service interface contracts to a new namespace, i.e from something like this:

```
namespace Old.Framework.Name
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ServiceEntriesResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SomeData { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ServiceResult GetServiceData();
    }
}
```

To this:

```
namespace New.Framework.Name
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ServiceEntriesResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SomeData { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ServiceResult GetServiceData();
    }
}
```

The only difference is the namespace, but it affects all parameter and return data structures as well as the service interface.

Now, we would very much like to keep new clients compatible with old services. At the moment, if I try to read from an old service with my new client, I get a null result. I can see that the correct service call is triggered on the server side, so it obviously manages to map something right, but the return data object is null.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Is this at all possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756373/datacontractserializer-compatibility-after-namespace-changed Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that actually helps a lot! I just need to update all my contracts with the magic namespace URL. I doesn't look all that pretty, but it certainly seems to work! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-names

And

[DataContractSerializer compatibility after namespace changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756373/datacontractserializer-compatibility-after-namespace-changed)

It appears that the default namespace is generated as:

```
http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Namespace
```

So in my case, i need to add the following to my DataContract attribute:

```
namespace New.Framework.Name
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Old.Framework.Name")]
    public class ServiceEntriesResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SomeData { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ServiceResult GetServiceData();
    }
}
```

This seems to work nicely in my case, so I just need to go through all my DataContracts and add this namespace