# DataContractSerializer cannot deserialize after namespace changed

Tags: c#, namespaces, datacontractserializer

I have 50 classes marked with `DataContractAttribute`.

These classes form a huge hierarchical tree, which is serialized/deserialized using the `DataContractSerializer` to xml.

All of them specify a custom datacontract namespace `[DataContract(Namespace="http://example.com")]`, except for 3 classes, which I've missed.

```
// Old class definitions 
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]  // <-- forgot ns
public class Type1{}
[DataContract(IsReference=true)] // <-- forgot ns
public class Type2{}
[DataContract(IsReference=true)] // <-- forgot ns
public class Type3{}
[DataContract(IsReference=true, Namespace="http://example.com")] // <-- 47 more like this
public class Type4{}
```

I want these 3 classes to use the same datacontract namespace as the other 47 classes.

After the change, all my previously-saved xmls fails to load.

```
// Changed to:
[DataContract(IsReference=true, Namespace="http://example.com")] // <-- changed ns
public class Type1{} 
[DataContract(IsReference=true, Namespace="http://example.com")] // <-- changed ns
public class Type2{} 
[DataContract(IsReference=true, Namespace="http://example.com")] // <-- changed ns
public class Type3{} 
[DataContract(IsReference=true, Namespace="http://example.com")]
public class Type4{}
```

I tried this method:

[DataContractSerializer - change namespace and deserialize file bound to old namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092274/datacontractserializer-change-namespace-and-deserialize-file-bound-to-old-name)

But got a `SerializationException` saying `Deserialized object with reference id 'i5' not found in stream.`

How can I deserialize xmls saved **before** and **after** the namespace change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally change the data contract and then create a script that parses the previously saved xmls to add the namespace info. Quick and simple.

Something like loading xmls as string and then calling:

```
xmlstr=xmlstr.Replace("<Type1>", "<Type1 xmlns:Namespace=\"http://example.com\">");
```

Or maybe create two classes (one with the old namespace and one with the new) create a mapping method so that you can deserialize the old xmls based on the old namespace and serialize them after mapping with the new namespace.